# Mode-local variables in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to have a global keyboard shortcut that shows the value of a variable. However, the variable's value could change according to the current major mode in the current buffer.

I tried to add the following to my `~/.emacs`:

```
(defun my-elisp-mode-setup ()
  (defvar-local *current-mode-var* "elisp-mode")
)
(defun my-sh-mode-setup ()
  (defvar-local *current-mode-var* "sh-mode")
)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-elisp-mode-setup)
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook 'my-sh-mode-setup)
```

If I now start Emacs with `emacs test.sh` and then type `M-x describe-variable *current-mode-var*` in the `test.sh` buffer, I get

```
*current-mode-var*'s value is "elisp-mode"

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

Documentation:
Not documented as a variable.
```

while I expected to get `*current-mode-var*'s value is "sh-mode"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables are evaled only at first declaration. All further declarations are skipped.
You need a `setq` instead.

Comment: Thanks! If I use `setq` how can then the variable become local?

Comment: It's buffer local after the declaration. This is something like declaring the type and assigning
in C: assignment doesn't change type. So `defvar-local` followed by `setq` will *not* change
the variable to non-local.

Comment: Ok.. Does this mean that you have to add a `(defvar-local *current-mode-var* nil)` in the `~/.emacs` and then use `setq` in the mode hooks?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Or declare in each mode, and setq in each mode. Doesn't hurt to declare stuff.

Comment: In emacs 24 you can use `setq-local`.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer official native package https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLocal .
It is better configurable, because you do not require `add-hook`

For example

```
(require 'mode-local)
(setq-mode-local sh-mode *current-mode-var* "sh-mode")
(setq-mode-local emacs-lisp-mode *current-mode-var* "elisp-mode")
```

Then by just changing mode cause changing the value of `*current-mode-var*`

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is examine a variable to determine the major mode (which it seems is what you are doing), then just examine variable `major-mode`.  That's what it's for.

And if you want a key/command to do that, then just create one:

```
(defun which-mode ()
  "Echo the current major mode in the echo area."
  (interactive)
  (message "Major mode: %s" major-mode))
```

Or use variable `mode-name` if you prefer a human-friendly major-mode name.

Answer (score 1):

`defvar-local` is a macro calling `defvar` and `make-variable-buffer-local` under the hood.

> **defvar SYMBOL [VALUE [DOC-STRING]**
>
> ... But if SYMBOL is not void, VALUE is not evaluated, and SYMBOL’s value is left unchanged...

You code should be:

```
(defvar-local *current-mode-var*)

(defun my-elisp-mode-setup ()
  (setq *current-mode-var* "elisp-mode"))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-elisp-mode-setup)

(defun my-sh-mode-setup ()
  (setq *current-mode-var* "sh-mode"))
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook 'my-sh-mode-setup)
```